# Dependency Injection in View Controller

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, singleton

I am trying to use dependency injection instead of following singletons. This is how I am trying to achieve. When I run the application I am having an error on `"No "decodeObject" candidates produce the expected contextual result type "ModelManager"` on that. Any idea how can I implement dependency injection in a right way?

My Model class:

```
class ModelManager {
var results: MyCustomClass

init(results: MyCustomClass) {
    self.results = results
}
func update(customDataInfo: MyCustomClass!) {
    self.results = customDataInfo
}
}
```

MyViewController.swift

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

private let modelManager: ModelManager

init(modelManager: ModelManager) {
    self.modelManager = modelManager
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.modelManager.modelManagerUpdate = self as ModelManagerUpdate
}

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self. modelManager = aDecoder.decodeObject(value(forKey: "modelManager") as ModelManager)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    super.encode(with: aCoder)
    aCoder.encode(self. modelManager, forKey: "modelManager")
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the `init?(coder:)` initialiser is being used suggests that your view controller is initialised from storyboard. If that is the case, storyboard does not contain `ModelManager`, thus it cannot decode it.

You can work around this by wrapping storyboard initialisation into your own method, e.g.:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var modelManager: ModelManager

    static func create(modelManager: ModelManager) -> MyViewController {
        let vc = /* instantiate vc from storyboard */
        vc.modelManager = modelManager
        return vc
    }
}
```

If the above method does not suit your needs, I would suggest you take a look at the [SwinjectStoryboard](https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard) framework. It provides - besides basic DI functionality - ability to inject dependencies to the view controllers initialised from storyboard.

Comment: But how to do instantiate vc from storyboard within a static function?

Comment: `myStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`

Comment: Don't you have to make modelManager as implicitly un-wrapped optional? since this class has no initialisers??

Answer (score 0):

Why you call `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)?` in ViewController init method?
Just call `super.init()` and it should fix.

Comment: because when i use that way i am getting an error like "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass "UIVIewController" :/ @Bio-Matic